# How many words of length n have at most k consecutive vowels?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, permutation, combinatorics

How many words of length n have at most k consecutive vowels?

Our alphabet has 21 consonants and 5 vowels.

Please  forgive me for not providing test cases. I don't have a test case because this was a phone interview problem given to a friend.

I am working on this problem from morning your little help be life saving for me.
I know problem statement is vague but if you can provide some hint on this dynamic programming pattern.

I found that since it is counting problem we can do something like this dp[i][j] = length of word i with j consecutive vowel .
I don't know how to proceed further .Please help in making recurrence!

Comment: include example test cases and expected results to make your question better to understand. Currently the question is not clear. While asking question : Include What do you know about the question, What would others expect to have in your question, What would readers of the question  gain after coming to your question. In short have clarity so as you get good answers. Put that effort to make it a good question as it will not only help you but others too in future. This is a community based platform.

Comment: does it mean that, given input words:[helloh, appeal, feedback, questn ]  , n=6 and k=2 then output should be 2 ? as only 3 words have length = 6( helloh, appeal, questn) and out of that only 2 ( the output ) have K ( 2) consecutive vowels ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working dynamic programming implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

#define n 5
#define k 2

int arr[n][k + 1];

int fill(int index, int currK){
    if(arr[n][currK] != 0) return arr[n][currK];  //if already calculated
    if(index == n - 1) {                          //base case
        arr[index][currK] = 21 + (currK ? 5 : 0);
        return arr[index][currK];
    }
    
    //recursive condition and step
    if(currK == 0) arr[n][currK] = 21 * fill(index + 1, k);
    else arr[n][currK] = 5 * fill(index + 1, currK - 1) + 21 * fill(index + 1, k);
    return arr[n][currK];   
}

int main(){
    memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));
    cout<<fill(0, k)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The idea is to have a `matrix[n][k + 1]`, where `matrix[i][j]` stores the possibilities for a word of size `i` where you have used `k - j` consecutive vowels.

Answer (score 1):

`dp[i][j][k]` - number of words of length `i`, ending with letter `j` and last `k` letters are `j`

base case:  `dp[0][0][1]=1` (index all allowed letters starting from 1)

filing table:

```
dp[i][j][k] = dp[i-1][j][k-1]

if(k == 1)
for j_prev in (0, mxJ):
for k_prev in (1, mxK):
dp[i][j][k]+=dp[i-1][j_prev][k_prev]
```

Answer (score 1):

n = length. k = max consecutive values. A word of length i is valid if it has at most k consecutive values.

Let f(i,j) = number of valid words of length i ending with j vowels.

```
f(0,0) = 1.
f(i,0) = 21 * (sum from j=0 to min(i-1,k) of f(i-1,j)), for i>0.
f(i,j) = 5*f(i-1, j-1) for 1 <= j <= k.
```

Solution is sum from j = 0 to k of f(n,j).

This takes O(k) memory, and O(n*k) time. The full table is O(nk), but you only need to retain the prior row at each step, where rows are lengths as in the example below.

Sample table for n=5, k=2

```
           0          1          2        

0          1        n/a        n/a
1         21          5        n/a
2        546        105         25
3     14,196      2,730        525
4    366,471     70,980     13,650
5  9,473,121  1,832,355    354,900
```

Result: sum of final row is 11,660,376

Comment: followed your approach getting wrong answer please help https://ideone.com/izsfRB

Comment: @akashking I forgot the 21* in the second step. f(i,0) is 21 times the sum of the prior row.

Comment: @akashking row 11: dp[i][0]+=dp[i-1][j]*21;

Comment: @akashking With the correction, your code returns 9,473,121, which is the 5,0 cell. IDK why it isn't returning the sum since it looks like you're summing the bottom row; can try to take a look later.

Comment: @akashking You had an off by one error in the second index. https://ideone.com/uZIOpC

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dynamic programming solution for the same.

I have used the dp array as dp[ length_of_string ][ 2 ], where

- dp[ i ][ 0 ] : total no of strings of length i with at most k consecutive vowels such that last character is a vowel
- dp[ i ][ 1 ] : total no of strings of length i with at most k consecutive vowels such that last character is a consonant

```
Case 1: ith character is consonant

No of choices for consonant, n = 21
dp[i][1] = (n) * (total number of string of length i-1 with at most k consecutive vowels)
dp[i][1] = 21 * (dp[i-1][0] + dp[i-1][1])
```

```
Case 2: ith character is vowel

if ith character is vowel, then it can be preceded by at most k-1 vowels

No of choices for vowels, n = 5

dp[i][0] = (no of strings of length i with at most k consecutive vowels such that last character is a vowel)
              + (no of strings of length i with at most k consecutive vowels such that last 2 characters are vowels) 
              + ... + (no of strings of length i with at most k consecutive vowels such that last k characters are vowels) 

Also, 
no of strings of length i with at most k consecutive
vowels such that last p characters are vowels = (5p)*(no of strings of length i-p with at most k consecutive vowels such that last character is a consonant)

So, 
dp[i][0] = (51 * dp[i-1][1]) + (52 * dp[i-2][1]) + ... + (5k * dp[i-k][1])
```

Finally,

The answer will be, Count = **dp[ length_of_string ][ 0 ] + dp[ length_of_string ][ 1 ]**

---

The C++ implementation for the logic is as follows:

```
   #include<bits/stdc++.h>
   #define mod 1000000007
   using namespace std;

   int solve(int wordLen, int maxVowels){
       long long dp[wordLen+1][2];

       dp[0][1] = dp[0][0] = 1;
       dp[1][1] = 21;
       dp[1][0]  = 5;

       for(int i  = 2;i<=wordLen;i++){

           dp[i][1] = (21*(dp[i-1][1]+dp[i-1][0])%mod)%mod;

           int k  = i, j = 1, p = 5;
           dp[i][0] = 0;

           while(k>0 && j<=maxVowels){
               dp[i][0] = (dp[i][0] + (p*dp[i-j][1])%mod)%mod;
               p = (p*5)%mod;
               k--;
               j++;
           } 
       }

       return (int)(dp[wordLen][0]+dp[wordLen][1])%mod;
   }

   int main(){
       cout<<solve(5, 3); 
       return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved using a regular expression. You might have to insist that correctness overways pedantry if you can show an adequate solution.

This Python searches an online dictionary of words using a character count for the word length and a regexp for the n consecutive vowels. I read your task description as meaning exactly `n` consecutive vowels rather than at least `n`.

### The Python

```
import re
import urllib


def getwords(length=5, url='http://wiki.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt'):
    "Return lowercased words of given number of characters"
    words = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode().strip().lower().split()
    return (w for w in words if len(w) ==length)

def get_special_words(length=5, consec_vowels=3):
    re_txt = r"[^aeiou\n]*([aeiou]{##CONSEC##})[^aeiou\n]*"
    regex = re.compile(re_txt.replace("##CONSEC##", str(consec_vowels)),
                       re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE | re.DOTALL)
    return (w for w in getwords(length) if regex.search(w))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wlen, consec = 7, 4
    
    print(f"Dictionary words of length {wlen} with {consec} consecutive vowels:")
    i = 0
    for i, w in enumerate(get_special_words(wlen, consec), 1):
        print(" ", w)
    print(f"\n{i} words found.")
```

### Output

```
Dictionary words of length 7 with 4 consecutive vowels:
  aqueous
  sequoia

2 words found.
```

## Ref.

The regex [described](https://regex101.com/r/DD3DEi/1).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C++ DP solution in a bottom-up approach

- `n` = length of string
- `m` = maximum number of consecutive vowels allowed
- `dp[i][j]` represents the number of distinct strings of length `i` and having `j` vowels consecutively as a suffix.

```
    vector<vector<int>> dp(n+1, vector<int>(m+1,0));
    dp[0][0] = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for(int j=m; j>=0; j--){
            // transition from dp[i-1][j] to dp[i][j+1] or dp[i][0]
            if(j == m){
                // we cannot add another vowel
                dp[i][0] += 21*dp[i-1][j];
            }
            else{
                dp[i][0] += 21*dp[i-1][j];
                dp[i][j+1] += 5*dp[i-1][j];
            }
        }
    }
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<=m; i++){
        ans += dp[n][i];
    }
    cout<<ans<<endl;
```